# Current Location method

Tags: android

I was wondering if there's a built in way of adding a 'get current location' button to the MapView, similar to the way you can set the zoom controls. I can't see a suitable-looking method in the API.

If not that's fine, I can write the code and add my own overlay but just wanted to check first.

Answer (score 1):

The most close solution would be to use [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html) and maybe toggle the location marker on/off by setting a button

Comment: Ah cool, that was easy, thanks. 

        MyLocationOverlay mlo = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        mlo.enableMyLocation();        
        mlo.enableCompass();
        mapOverlays.add(mlo);